# Where do I put the code for refreshing a dynamic date-time value in a react native mobile app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a mobile application in 'visual studio code' using 'react native'. I need coding-software help.
Dynamic text value react, date.now - item.date react native, A date-time is coming from the database, I want to remove it from the date-time and refresh it every 1 minute. How can I do that?
And in this code sequence, in order; where do i put the correct codes? Where do I write the codes? To avoid errors.
Code sequence, from start to finish; are as follows

```
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, Image, textDecorationLine} from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';


import {firebase} from '../config';

const Homepage = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Data');
    

    useEffect(async () => {
        todoRef
        .onSnapshot(
            querySnapshot => {
                const users = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const { price, new_price, food_name, restaurant, piece, img,   } = doc.data()
                    users.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        price,
                        new_price,
                        food_name,
                        restaurant,
                        piece,
                        img,
                        
                    })
                    
                })
                setUsers(users)
            }
        )
    }, [])

    return(
        <View style={{ flex:1, marginTop:10}}>
            
             
            <FlatList
            style={{height:'100%'}}
            data={users}
            numColumns={1}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            
            <Pressable
                style={styles.container} >
                  <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                     <View style={styles.box}>

                     <Text style={styles.itemFood}>{item.food_name}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemRestaurant}>{item.restaurant}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemPrice}>{item.price}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemPiece}>{item.piece}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemNew}>{item.new_price}</Text>

                    <Image style={styles.itemİmg} 
                    source={{ uri: item.img }}  />
                    
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Pressable>
     )}
             />   
        </View>
   )
}

export default Homepage
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        margin:5,
        padding:11,
        backgroundColor:'#FEA82F',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'#FEA82F'
        
    },
    box:{
        backgroundColor:'#FFC288',
        elevation:7,
        shadowColor:'#026efd',
        alignItems:'center',
        height:130,
        width:340,
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
    innerContainer:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection:'column',
    },
    itemFood:{
        top:115,
        left:180,
        alignSelf:'baseline',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop:0,
        fontSize:16
    },
```

On this code page, where should I type the correct codes?

Comment: As far as general approach, I think yours is basically correct.  Every time there is a change, your onSnapshot callback will get call.  You'll then recreate the state, and display it. 

Could you please clarify the following: "Dynamic text value react, date.now - item.date react native, A date-time is coming from the database, I want to remove it from the date-time and refresh it every 1 minute. "

Are you saying you want to add an optimization to only add things that have have been added or changed in the last minute?  Please clarify w short sentances.

Comment: This is a 'food ordering' app. Business - restaurant owners will add discounted products at certain hours. For products that are on sale, there will be a time counter ( example: 2 hours). 
Example: At 19.00 in the evening, a 2-hour discount will be applied. It will end at 21.00.
It needs to be on the current date and time in the application.
The time counter will count backwards.
( 2:00:00 , 1:59:59, 1:58 ) in hours, minutes and seconds, it will count down.